# Rails 4.2 Devise + ActiveAdmin, redirect to sign_in page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, activeadmin

There are various questions on Stack concerning this issue, but none of the solutions work for me.

I setup Devise and ActiveAdmin on Rails 4.2.  I'm able to login to the Admin Dashboard at `/admin`, however I am immediately redirected to the `new_user_session_path`.  After this, if I visit `/admin`, I am logged in as the admin and can access the Dashboard with no problem.

Any ideas on why I am getting redirected?

Thank you.

I have added this line of code to active_admin.rb in my initializers folder:

`config.skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!`

This the log:

```
Started POST "/admin/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-13 12:43:35 -0500
Processing by ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kHYu9AHzbUAbs+A2JTC16P3S4tynjJmrtam++Wlze19Z4encRLdNlqm1m1q2zaU+iiXbxZhVeXQBt0IwdpsXLg==", "admin_user"=>{"email"=>"admin@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]
", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Login"}
  AdminUser Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."email" = $1  ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["email", "admin@example.com"]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "admin_users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = $1, "current_sign_in_at" = $2, "sign_in_count" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "admin_users"."id" = $5  [["last_sign_in_at", "2015-02-13 15:20:35.802130
"], ["current_sign_in_at", "2015-02-13 17:43:35.624351"], ["sign_in_count", 15], ["updated_at", "2015-02-13 17:43:35.630808"], ["id", 1]]
   (0.8ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://comicbookdb.dev/comic_books
Completed 302 Found in 125ms (ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)

Processing by ComicBooksController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-13 12:43:35 -0500
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
```

So obviously it is redirecting my admin user first to `/comic_books` and then because the admin user is unauthorized, to `/users/sign_in`.

I'm not sure the best way to solve this issue.  Perhaps a gem like Pundit would help?  This is really starting to drive me nuts.

Thank you.

Here is my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  root  'static_pages#welcome'
  devise_for :users
  resources :comic_books
  resources "contacts", only: [:new, :create]

  get 'welcome'       => 'static_pages#welcome'
  get 'about'         => 'high_voltage/pages#show', id: 'about'
  get 'contact'       => 'contacts#new'
```

Comment: I'm experiencing this exact same issue. Any chance you've solved this by now?